# Button won't work on my animation

Tags: html, css

I made an animation some days ago using css3, it's basicaly a slideshow. The thing is that whenever I try to insert a button into the slideshow, the one on the first slide is not clickable, but the one on the second is.

HTML :

```
<div class="slide1">
        <div class="button_container1">
            <div class="button_bg"></div>
            <button class="button_skin">En savoir plus</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
        <div class="button_container2">
            <div class="button_bg"></div>
            <button class="button_skin">En savoir plus</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
.slide1{
    background: url(images/slide_1.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 425px;
    -webkit-animation: slide1 21s infinite;
    animation: slide1 21s infinite;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.button_container1{
  width: 87px;
  height: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  bottom: 69px;
}
@keyframes slide1 {
  0%   { opacity: 0;}
  2%  { opacity: 1; }
  33% { opacity: 1;}
  35% { opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
.slide2{
    background: url(images/slide_2.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 425px;
    -webkit-animation: slide2 21s infinite;
    animation: slide2 21s infinite;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -425px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.button_container2{
  width: 87px;
  height: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  left : 22px;
  bottom: 69px;
}
@keyframes slide2 {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  33%  { opacity: 0; }
  36% { opacity: 1;}
  66% { opacity: 1;}
  68% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using `@keyframes`, use `transition: all 1s ease-in-out;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your second slide is going over your first slide so when you're clicking you clicking the second slide and not the first button.

You can change the z-index of the first button to bring it to the front.

```
z-index: 1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jn4tch7k/1/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the div2 is above the div1, you could reduce the size of the div 2 and then you can use both buttons,you can work with guide, using  `border:1px blue solid;` in slide1, and  `border:1px red solid;` for slide2

please check it [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zz9bff5j/)